# OverlayFS: overlay everything except special dirs

Tags: overlayfs

How do I use OverlayFS to overlay my complete system except some special dirs? As far as I understand from reading the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/overlayfs.html?highlight=overlayfs) this is how I would overlay my complete system: (I'd like the overlay to only exist in RAM)

```
mount -t overlay overlay -olowerdir=/,upperdir=/dev/shm
```

However I didn't find anything on dirs that can be excluded from the overlay. Is this even possible?